# How to create typedef for a pointer

Tags: c++

I am trying to create memory for a pointer.I have a code like:

```
#ifdef  SOURCE_CODE_EXPORTED

static struct BasicIDymosimStruct*basicI = 0;
static struct BasicDDymosimStruct*basicD = 0;
struct BasicIDymosimStruct*getBasicIDymosimStruct() {
    return basicI;
}
struct BasicDDymosimStruct*getBasicDDymosimStruct() {
    return basicD;
}
void setBasicStruct(double*d, int*i) {
    basicI = (struct BasicIDymosimStruct*)(i);
    basicD = (struct BasicDDymosimStruct*)(d);
}
struct DymosimSimulator dataNoDll = { 0,0,"?????","?????",FALSE_ };
struct DymosimSimulator*dataNoDllPtr = 0;
#endif
```

For memory allocation i am writing code like :

```
dymBasicD = (struct *) (calloc(1, sizeof(struct BasicDDymosimStruct)));

dymBasicI = (struct *) (calloc(1, sizeof(struct BasicIDymosimStruct)));
```

However,i am getting an Error saying

> :- C2332 :cannot convert from '*'to basicIDymosimStruct.

Note : I am mixing this C code with c++.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: First of all: `struct *` what? Secondly: If you allocate memory in C++ use `new` or `new[]`. The pointers returned can be passed to C functions. Thirdly: `basicI = (struct BasicIDymosimStruct*)(i)` *what*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you mean, `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared`

Comment: 1) You cannot mix C and C++ source code! If you compile as C++, it **is** C++, not C! Identical syntax does not mean identical semantics! 2) **Never ever** `typedef` a pointer to a data type! 3) Provide a [mcve] and the information required. Read [ask].

Comment: In C, the cast is not required (and is actually a really bad technique) so `dymBasicD = calloc(1, sizeof(struct BasicDDymosimStruct))` will do.   In C++, you will need a cast, as in `dymBasicD = (struct BasicDDymosimStruct *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct BasicDDymosimStruct))`   (if using the cast, the `struct` keyword is needed in C and optional in C++).    Same for `basicI`.   In C++, better to avoid `calloc()` entirely.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `typedef` a pointer, use the following syntax for C/C++:

```
typedef int* IntPointer;
```

And for C++:

```
using IntPointer = int*;
```

If you want to typedef a **pointer to a function**:

```
typedef /*return value type*/ (*t_somefunc)(/* type1 */, /* type2 etc */);
```